# How to add multiple-column Items to TListBox?

Tags: delphi, listbox, delphi-11-alexandria

In a 32-bit VCL Application in Windows 10 in Delphi 11.1 Alexandria, I am trying to add multiple-column Items to TListBox. The CHM Libraries Reference for VCL in the Vcl.StdCtrls.TCustomListBox.Items topic has the following tip:
[image]

So I created the following VCL Application test project:

**DPR:**

```
program TListBoxMultiColumn;

uses
  Vcl.Forms,
  Unit1 in 'Unit1.pas' {Form1};

{$R *.res}

begin
  Application.Initialize;
  Application.MainFormOnTaskbar := True;
  Application.CreateForm(TForm1, Form1);
  Application.Run;
end.
```

**PAS:**

```
unit Unit1;

interface

uses
  Winapi.Windows, Winapi.Messages, System.SysUtils, System.Variants, System.Classes, Vcl.Graphics,
  Vcl.Controls, Vcl.Forms, Vcl.Dialogs, Vcl.StdCtrls;

type
  TForm1 = class(TForm)
    ListBox1: TListBox;
    Button1: TButton;
    procedure Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
  private
    { Private declarations }
  public
    { Public declarations }
  end;

var
  Form1: TForm1;

implementation

{$R *.dfm}

procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
begin
  ListBox1.Items.Add('First Column'^I'Second Column');
  ListBox1.Items.Add('1'^I'2');
  ListBox1.Items.Add('4'^I'5');
end;

end.
```

**DFM:**

```
object Form1: TForm1
  Left = 0
  Top = 0
  Caption = 'TListBox MultiColumn Test'
  ClientHeight = 191
  ClientWidth = 368
  Color = clBtnFace
  Font.Charset = DEFAULT_CHARSET
  Font.Color = clWindowText
  Font.Height = -15
  Font.Name = 'Segoe UI'
  Font.Style = []
  Position = poScreenCenter
  PixelsPerInch = 120
  TextHeight = 20
  object ListBox1: TListBox
    Left = 0
    Top = 0
    Width = 241
    Height = 191
    Margins.Left = 4
    Margins.Top = 4
    Margins.Right = 4
    Margins.Bottom = 4
    Align = alLeft
    Columns = 2
    ItemHeight = 20
    TabOrder = 0
    ExplicitHeight = 413
  end
  object Button1: TButton
    Left = 260
    Top = 20
    Width = 94
    Height = 31
    Margins.Left = 4
    Margins.Top = 4
    Margins.Right = 4
    Margins.Bottom = 4
    Caption = 'Button1'
    TabOrder = 1
    OnClick = Button1Click
  end
end
```

However, the result is not what is promised in the documentation:

[image]

So how can I add multiple-column Items to a `TListBox`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You must set the [`TabWidth`](https://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/Vcl.StdCtrls.TListBox.TabWidth) property to a suitable, large enough value:

```pascal
ListBox1.TabWidth := 100;
ListBox1.Items.Add('First Column'^I'Second Column');
ListBox1.Items.Add('1'^I'2');
ListBox1.Items.Add('4'^I'5');
```

Bonus information: You may wonder why `^I` is used here. Well, since *I* is the 9th letter in the English alphabet, `^I` is equal to `#9`, that is, the tabulator character.

I would write this

```pascal
ListBox1.TabWidth := 100;
ListBox1.Items.Add('First Column'#9'Second Column');
ListBox1.Items.Add('1'#9'2');
ListBox1.Items.Add('4'#9'5');
```

Actually, [the current version](https://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/Alexandria/en/Vcl.StdCtrls.TCustomListBox.Items) of the documentation states

> Tip: If you have a list box with tab stops enabled (`TabStop` property) and you want to add data to specific columns, you can set the `TabWidth` property to obtain a list box in which individual lines can be displayed in columns, as long as they use tabs in their text, as shown in the snippet below (notice #9 is the tab character).

This is a better description, since it mentions the `TabWidth` property, uses `#9` instead of `^I`, and doesn't misuse the word "parameter". However, its reference to `TabStop` is utterly nonsense. The `TabStop` property is about the form's tab order.

Comment: Thanks! I wonder why this **indispensable** information is not included in the documentation?

Comment: @user1580348: Embarcadero is a company with limited resources, so the docs aren't always as good as they should be.

Comment: I've come up with a DIRTY EMPIRICAL algorithm to calculate the first of two column widths: https://www.screencast.com/t/1b7uUaCDa8D

Comment: The DIRTY EMPIRICAL algorithm gets this acceptable result: https://www.screencast.com/t/nqlBnEOf2q

Comment: I used your proposed example: https://www.screencast.com/t/6TtGlS43eJO6 That leads to this problem: https://www.screencast.com/t/uptiSLEMK4JJ You can see that when selecting an item, the text in the first column is selected but the text in the second column becomes almost invisible! Ho can this problem be avoided?

Comment: @user1580348: That doesn't happen on my side. What properties have you set on the list box?

Comment: This is the ListBox1 object: https://www.screencast.com/t/Wmhlfxfhrh

Comment: @user1580348: You should not set `Columns`. Let it be `0`. `Columns` is used to automatically partition single-column items into columns.

Comment: So `Columns` and `TabWidth` + `#9` are two entirely different concepts. The comment "Tip: To add data to specific columns, you need to use the ^I parameter, as shown in Items." in the docs is *very* misleading.

Comment: Thanks! I've learned another helpful thing: **Never trust the documentation!**

Comment: Now I have optimized the whole thing for a variable number of columns: https://www.screencast.com/t/qbiLoHsRZ

Comment: `TListBox` really doesn't have *proper/good* column support. This is *simulated* columns at best. Personally, I would use `TListView` in `vsReport` mode instead, that uses *proper* columns.

Comment: @RemyLebeau is absolutely right: if you need a multi-column list (report) control, the `TListView` is the thing Win32 has to offer. `TListBox` is a much simpler control suitable for simpler tasks. (It's a bit like a true table in a Microsoft Word document vs. a "table" made from tabs and suitable tab stops.)

Comment: Unfortunately, the documentation omits another fact: The fake columns work only if `ListBox.Style = lbStandard`. It does NOT work if `ListBox.Style = lbOwnerDrawVariable`!

Comment: But that is almost expected, since owner drawing means "please, Windows, don't draw the items, I want to write my own code that draws the items" so with owner drawing it is up to the programmer to make sure that #9 is handled correctly, no?

Comment: This is logical, but the documentation should nevertheless mention it.

Comment: "_This account is temporarily suspended to cool down. The suspension period ends on Nov 21 at 21:51._" - this explains the score of 1. If he returns with a different account he can be spotted by his [PA-Soft](https://www.pa-soft.com/about.html) brand in the code/GIFs.